# SSL error during run of local host server in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I followed [this](https://dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes) to remove ssl error but editing in server.xml is not working

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslEnabledProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"  />
```

Comment: So where did you configure your keystore? No certificate, no SSL.

Answer (score 0):

SSL always needs a certificate on the server side, otherwise it would not be able to provide encryption.

So follow step 1 of your linked instruction and create a keypair via

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

Then answer the question and add the necessary attributes to your connector:

```
keystoreFile="/path/to/keystore/.keystore" keystorePass="keystorePassword"
```

Note that this will use a self-signed certificate that will produce security-warnings in the browser.